# No way to solve this without modifying Microsoft header?

Tags: atl, visual-c++-2010, wtl

Trying to compile this old VC++ 6.0 program in VC++ 2010. This ATL/WTL stuff is giving me lots of problems. I downloaded and have linked to the latest WTL (as far as I know) wtl71.

I am getting compile errors in atlmisc.h:

atlmisc.h(1159): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const char *' to 'TCHAR *'

I've searched the 'net, and the answers that come up call for modifying the stock MS atlmisc.h file!

Am I missing something here? What do I need to do to get this to compile?

Comment: This is a complicated set of 15 years old code an a fresh compiler, and libraries either aged versions or fresh ones. Perhaps you'd be better off using latest compiler, latest ATL (included with Studio), latest WTL from their website, and code with updates and amendments required to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time I've seen that error, it's because I've been trying to build a Unicode application. In a Unicode application, the TCHAR* is a short* or wchar_t* rather than a char*.

I'd suggest checking your project settings and making sure that in the project properties, General > Character Set is set to Use Multi-Byte Character Set.